# Clang LLVM 1.0 Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, clang

Tried to add a new category and now im getting this error

```
ProcessPCH /Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tutorial-dmhshuqgvfykctbdzxopvinwcvpd/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/tutorial-Prefix-azwowysritanixcinyybieddtusa/tutorial-Prefix.pch.pth tutorial/tutorial-Prefix.pch normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/Home/Developer/tutorial
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -g -Wno-sign-conversion "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -iquote /Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tutorial-dmhshuqgvfykctbdzxopvinwcvpd/Build/Intermediates/tutorial.build/Debug/tutorial.build/tutorial-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tutorial-dmhshuqgvfykctbdzxopvinwcvpd/Build/Intermediates/tutorial.build/Debug/tutorial.build/tutorial-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tutorial-dmhshuqgvfykctbdzxopvinwcvpd/Build/Intermediates/tutorial.build/Debug/tutorial.build/tutorial-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tutorial-dmhshuqgvfykctbdzxopvinwcvpd/Build/Intermediates/tutorial.build/Debug/tutorial.build/tutorial-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tutorial-dmhshuqgvfykctbdzxopvinwcvpd/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tutorial-dmhshuqgvfykctbdzxopvinwcvpd/Build/Intermediates/tutorial.build/Debug/tutorial.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tutorial-dmhshuqgvfykctbdzxopvinwcvpd/Build/Intermediates/tutorial.build/Debug/tutorial.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tutorial-dmhshuqgvfykctbdzxopvinwcvpd/Build/Products/Debug --serialize-diagnostics /Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tutorial-dmhshuqgvfykctbdzxopvinwcvpd/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/tutorial-Prefix-azwowysritanixcinyybieddtusa/tutorial-Prefix.pch.dia -c /Users/Home/Developer/tutorial/tutorial/tutorial-Prefix.pch -o /Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tutorial-dmhshuqgvfykctbdzxopvinwcvpd/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/tutorial-Prefix-azwowysritanixcinyybieddtusa/tutorial-Prefix.pch.pth -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/tutorial-dmhshuqgvfykctbdzxopvinwcvpd/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/tutorial-Prefix-azwowysritanixcinyybieddtusa/tutorial-Prefix.pch.d

clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Home/Developer/tutorial/tutorial/tutorial-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Like @TonyTheLion said, there's no error in what you posted. Please post some code too, if you can, that'll help figuring out what the problem is.

Comment: Is the file red in Xcode, by any chance?

Comment: none of the files are red.. just the error. i think i added an objective-c header file to an os-x project.. but i deleted it so i dont understand why im getting an error @SimonGermain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do what @Ramy was suggesting or you can simply remove the `Prefix Header` from your target build settings. Simply remove the content of that field, you can't delete the actual field.

[image: Target Build Settings]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your target is empty, and that you have deleted the prefix file for mistake.

Select your project target (the azure icon at the top of the groups hierarchy on the left), select the target (equal to the project name) under "targets", then select the build phases tag and and add files to the compile sources.

As for the prefix file, you may want to re-create it, it'n names "YourProjectName-Prefix.pch". This is the content of my prefix file:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#endif
```

Try it, and consider that you may always want to build a project from scratch if something goes wrong and you haven't time to fix it.

Comment: @H2CO3 I see both osx and ios tags.

Comment: @user1779598 mostly for these two lines: "clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Home/Developer/tutorial/tutorial/tutorial-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files"

Answer (score 0):

I received this error because I accidentally gave a source file a -m flag instead of a -w flag. Here's to fat fingers.